# Can I play my original Skyrim save games on the legendary version?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I want to get all of the DLCs, but it will be cheaper to just buy the 'legendary' Skyrim pack rather than each DLC separately.

I'm pretty far in my saved games on regular version and was wondering if they'll also be recognised on the legendary version?

This is on Xbox 360

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your old saves will work. Think of it as buying DLC, since that's what it is. What the Legendary Edition will do is update Skyrim and install the DLC packs. It's the same game, with the same save file format. That was also the case with all Bethesda games and their subsequent GOTY editions.

Comment: While it's true that the save files would be the same, Fallout 3 and Fallout 3 GOTY *are* separate games on Steam for example (different app IDs), so I can see where sometimes it can be confusing :)

Comment: Confusing for sure. I had to do the same research on the matter when I bought Fallout 3 GOTY after playing Fallout 3. Turns out the saves aren't at all located in a directory, connected to the Steam app, so the game doesn't care that you're using a different release.